# Advice on reading multiple text files into an array with Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm currently writing out a program in Ruby, which I'm fairly new at, and it requires multiple text files to be pushed into an array line by line.

I am currently unable to actually test my code since I'm at work and this is for personal use, but I'm seeking advice to see if my code is correct.  I knows how to read a file and push it to the array.  If possible can someone check it over and advise if I have the correct idea?  I'm self taught regarding Ruby and have no-one to check my work.

I understand if this isn't the right place for trying to get this sort of advice and it's deleted/locked.  Apologies if so.

```rb
contentsArray = []

Dir.glob('filepath').each do |filename|
  next if File.directory?(filename)
  r = File.open("#{path}#{filename}")
  r.each_line { |line| contentsArray.push line}
end
```

I'm hoping this snippet will take the lines from multiple files in the same directory and stick them in the array so I can later splice what's in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the question.

First let's assume that 'filepath' is something like the target pattern you want to glob in `Dir.glob('filepath')` (I used `Dir.glob('src/*.h').each do |filename|` in my test).

After that, `File.open("#{path}#{filename}")` prepends another path to the already complete path you'll have in `filename`.

And lastly, although this is probably not the problem, the code opens the file and never closes it. The `IO` object provides a `readlines` method that takes care of opening and closing the file for you.

Here's some working code that you can adapt:

```
contentsArray = []

Dir.glob('filepath').each do |filename|
  next if File.directory?(filename)
  lines = IO.readlines(filename)
  contentsArray.concat(lines)
end

puts "#{contentsArray.length} LINES"
```

Here are references to the Ruby doc's for the `IO::readlines` and `Array::concat` methods used:

- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.5/IO.html#method-i-readlines
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.5/Array.html#method-i-concat

As an alternative to using the goto (`next`) the code could conditionally execute on files, like this:

```
  if File.file?(filename)
    lines = IO.readlines(filename)
    contentsArray.concat(lines)
  end
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you.  I wasn't too far off, not bad for someone taking a complete guess.  I'll give it a go in a few hours and see what happens.  Thanks for this.